Clapping in shul
Can anybody point me to sources (not opinions) which discuss whether or not it is permitted to clap inside the sanctuary of a beit knesseth, leaving aside the issue of clapping on shabbat?

Why do you think it would be an issue?

clapping, as in a round of applause? or to keep a beat when praying / singing?

Why leave aside the main explicit prohibition?

Are you specifically asking during the week? Or do you mean according to those who permit clapping on Shabbat?

@יהושע I suppose this one is a more general question, like is it possible to clap for a derashah or a groom getting married usw.

This is quite fascinating. If you google "applause in shul" you will find numerous "synagogue etiquette guides" primarily from denominations other than Orthodox deprecating the practice of clapping in shul as disrespectful.
On the other hand: this answer from
https://shulchanaruchharav.com/from-the-ravs-desk-clapping-on-shabbos-for-standing-ovation/ article by Rabbi Yaakov Goldstein entitled Clapping on Shabbos for standing ovation does not explicitly address the clapping in shul but certainly appears to permit clapping in shul as it permits clapping in the context of "singing in shul by Davening."
"It is permitted to clap hands the normal way on Shabbos for the sake of an applause or standing ovation. However, it is forbidden to clap hands the normal way for the sake of music or while a song is being sung. However, the widespread custom is to be lenient and permit clapping hands the normal way when one is singing songs for the sake of joy of a mitzvah [i.e. Shabbos Niggunim, singing in shul by Davening and Farbrengen]."
The article by Rabbi Yaakov Goldstein cites numerous sources as follows:
Sources: See regarding the general restriction against clapping and the dispute relevant in today’s times: Admur 339:2; 338:1; Michaber 339:3; Rama 339:3; Rambam Shabbos 23:5; Mishneh Beitza 36b; M”B 339:10; Aruch Hashulchan 339:9 [rules that the form of clapping and dancing done today was never included in the original decree of the Sages and hence it is always permitted to be done on Shabbos even not for a Mitzvah purpose.]; See regarding the allowance to clap in the abnormal way: Admur 339:2; Michaber 339:3; See regarding the allowance to clap for noisemaking and to applaud someone: M”B 339:9; Biur Halacha “Oi Al Haluach”; Az Nidbaru 13:14; Piskeiy Teshuvos 339:5; see regarding the allowance to clap the normal way for a song of Simcha shel Mitzvah: M”B 339:10; Shaar HaTziyon 339:7; Minchas Elazar 1:29; Nimukei Orach Chayim 339; Ashel Avraham [Butshatsh]; Shaareiy Halacha Uminhag 2:165
So the answer in this case appears to be: be aware of the etiquette and accepted practice in the shul that you are attending as well as the halacha

Thank you, as this gives me a solid halachic answer.

Thank you, Steve. If you are satisfied with my answer. Please accept it.
